# How to configure VPN server on Ubuntu

Tags: vpn

Can any one explain me to how to configure VPN server in Ubuntu 14..? am about to deploy a VPN server for my firm next week please help me..
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Need more info. What is your goal? Is your VPN server also your LAN gateway? Are you only going to need access to the subnet your VPN will reside on?

ie. Small office with ISP modem/router providing network on one subnet  or
    Large office with multiple gateways/switches/routers/subnets

etc..